# PHP Ajax Autocomplete

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-autocomplete

I am having a problem with my auto complete code and was wondering how to fix.

I have an element in the HTML document called country. I would like to pass the value of the Country select dynamically to the ajax page defined in the autocomplete. How can i do that?

I tried adding a parameter but it always get the first element in the select.

I also tried adding data in the autocomplete but no luck.

Below is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var country = document.getElementById("country");

    $("#postcode").autocomplete({
        source:'getpostcodes.php?country='+document.getElementById("country").value,
        minLength:1,
        data: {country:document.getElementById("country")}
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you post some more context like the HTML?

Comment: It's probably just a case of getting the selected option rather than the select's value, i.e. `$('#country option:selected').val()`